# Separate file in React for all Api requests

Tags: reactjs, api, import, react-hooks, export

I have a file Api.js to fetch the data from all (there are more to implement) the Api's I use:

```
import {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const GetUsers = () => {
    const [responseArray, setresponseArray] = useState([]);

    axios
    .get("http://localhost:8080/api/Users", {
        headers: {
            "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.statusText === "OK") {
            setresponseArray(res.data);
            }
        return responseArray;
        } else {
            console.log("Error: ", res);
        }
        });
};
```

And I have a second file to call it i.e. ShowData.js

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {getUsers} from "./Api";

const Properties = () => {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers();
    }, []);

    return("Do something with the data")
```

I get the error "Invalid hook call" because I'm breaking the Rules of Hooks with useState.

But I need that Hook to store the api response in it. So I am looking for ideas of how to design this differently (and correct).

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. I just changed the loop depending on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a custom hook, like this: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_customhooks.asp

For your case:

Api.js

```
const useUsers = () => {
  const [responseArray, setResponseArray] = useState([])
  axios
    .get(
      // ...
    )
    .then(
      // ...
      setResponseArray(res.data)
    )

    return [responseArray]
}
```

ShowData.js

```
const Properties = () => {
  const [users] = useUsers()
  return (
    // do something with users
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I can not call the fetch in useEffect of ShowData.js (breaking the Rules of Hooks)

Comment: You wouldn't call the custom hook in useEffect of ShowData.js. You would call it in the main function block. Like in that link I gave you, `const [data] = useFetch("...")` is called in the main function block of the `Home` component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).